# Computing $E[X^2 \mid X > \frac{1}{2}]$ given $f(x)$ & Conditional Distribution Question

Tags: probability

I have $f(x) = (1-x)I(0<x<1) + (x-1)I(1<x<2)$ and wish to compute $E\left[\ X^2 \mid X > \frac{1}{2}\right ]$.

Sln from the prof says that $E\left[\ X^2 \mid X > \frac{1}{2}\right ] = \frac{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} x^2f(x)dx}{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} f(x)dx}$ immediately on the first line and then it continues with the integration.

Why? Don't we have to find the conditional probability of the function first?

I know that $E[u(x),y] = \int_{\infty}^{\infty}u(x)f(x|y)dx$, but our function is single-variable. How do we find $f(x|y)$?

Comment: @Henry Oh. For some reason, I did not think that the denominator was the marginal density for the function. I am used to the problems having at least two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{ f(x) I(x \gt \tfrac12)}{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) I(x \gt \tfrac12)\, dx}=\dfrac{ f(x) I(x \gt \frac12)}{\displaystyle \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx} $ is the conditional density.

The given solution multiplies this by $x^2$ and then integrates to find the conditional expectation $E[X^2 \mid X \gt \frac12]$.

Answer (score 1):

> Why? Don't we have to find the conditional probability of the function first?

You already have, because: $f_{X\mid X > 1/2}(x) = \dfrac{f_X(x)\cdot\mathbf 1_{x > 1/2}}{\int\limits_{1/2}^\infty f_X(x)\operatorname d x}$